Unique Beveled Glass Colonial Grid Windows
I may need to replace some of the windows in my house and would like to match the other ones present. But the windows in the house are unique and I can't find them anywhere online. They're colonial grid windows but instead of plastic strips making up the grid, the glass on the interior pane is beveled in a grid pattern. Picture below if that doesn't make sense. Has anyone seen these before and know where I might find them. I'm curious if they have a special name because I can't find them with what I'm searching. Thanks!


Might need to search for custom window glass.  Making them should not be too difficult with the rights tools that are found at a glass shop.

Start with taking your pictures to a window supplier, perhaps first also looking for any tiny coded text in the corners of the double-glazed units, or other clues to the maker. I tried "illusion muntins", "clear muntins", and a few other variations without getting anything to match these. Muntins being "the grid" in a windowpane.

Note that what term to search for or call them is on topic, and where to get them is not. You might want to [edit] to remove where to get them from the question.

I think one term is cut glass, or cut glass designs, which is different than cutting/cut glass

Agree with the suggestion to call local glass shops, show them the photo, give them dimensions, and ask for a quote. The one near me, at least, likes a challenge.
